# How do I make bootstrap card go next to each other when they are generated by django?

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, jinja2

[image]I made a blog in django but there is a problem. Whenever I create a new blog post it sends the bootstrap card downwards and not next to the other bootstrap card, meaning its going vertically and not horizontally.

```
{% extends 'portfolio/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}Blog{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
<div class="container text-center">
    <h2>Blogs</h2>
    <h2>PyPatriot has posted {{ blogs.count }} Blog{{ blogs.count | pluralize }}</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {% for blog in blogs %}
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="{{ blog.cover_photo.url }}" class="card-img-top" width="230" height="230">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">{{ blog.title }}</h4>
                    <h6>{{ blog.date | date:'M d Y'}}</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ blog.description | truncatechars:70 }}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'blog:detail' blog.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
                </div>

            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>


{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Look what its doing to the blog posts I add from django admin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't need this:
`<div class="col-sm-6">`
As this stuffs all your cards in one column of half a screen width.

Next, Bootstrap cards stack like normal `<div>` elements. To make them go side by side you have to make them do so, either by building your own layout, like using @ImustAdmit's solution, or flexbox or some other method, or by using Bootstraps's `.card-columns` class ([see here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns)). 
In your case just wrap a `<div class="card-column">` around your loop.

To change the layout for different breakpoints you can use something like

```
.card-columns {
  @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
    column-count: 5;
  }
}
```

(this is straight from the Bootstrap card page).

You can also use 3rd party libraries like [Isotope.js](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for more fancy layouts, or use flexbox for a more DIY solution. Basically treat cards as normal divs, or use Bootstrap helper classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `forloop.counter` to count cards

This is part of my website

```
{% for post in object_list %}
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %} <div class="row"> {%  endif %}
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card article">
      <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><img class="responsive opacity" src="{{ post.img_url }}" alt=""></a> 
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="date-field">{{ post.created_on|date:"d.m.y" }} / {{post.field}}</p>
            <h2 class="article-title"><a class="link-article" href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
          <div class="content">
            {{ post.content|safe|truncatewords:35 }}
          </div>
          <div class="button-wrapper"><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><button class="button button1" >Czytaj dalej</button></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{%  if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 or forloop.last %}</div><br>{%  endif %}
{%  endfor %}
```

It would create 3 cards next to each other in the row.

If you want create more or less cards per row you need to change `divisibleby` in `if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3` and number of columns in `<div class="col-md-4">`

In your case it would looks like:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <h2>Blogs</h2>
    <h2>PyPatriot has posted {{ blogs.count }} Blog{{ blogs.count | pluralize }}</h2>
{% for blog in blogs %}
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %} <div class="row"> {%  endif %}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="{{ blog.cover_photo.url }}" class="card-img-top" width="230" height="230">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{ blog.title }}</h4>
                <h6>{{ blog.date | date:'M d Y'}}</h6>
                <p class="card-text">{{ blog.description | truncatechars:70 }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'blog:detail' blog.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            </div>
    </div>
{%  if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 or forloop.last %}</div><br>{%  endif %}
{%  endfor %}
```

Comment: nothing extra in view. You just to need to manipulate html template using ```forloop``` built-in tag

Comment: bro it is not working, it still shows it vertically

Comment: ok now its working thank you and could you explain the theory behind the jinja tags?

Comment: Its not jinja tag. It is built in django template language tag. It imitate ```for i in range(0,4)``` if my response helped you accept my answer :)